# Admin Post Table - Remove Title Edit Link

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

I am using a plugin which requires the user to have the `edit_essays` capability to be able to view the list of Essays and Grade them, so I cannot solve this problem by editing capabilities (I am aware that the user will still be able to edit if they manually entered the correct edit URL.)

I have removed the 'Edit' and 'Quick Edit' post row actions, but I do not want to user to be able to click the title to edit the post.

How do I remove the link from the Title in the Admin post table for this post type?
e.g. From image below, remove the link from '**Test Question 1**'

[image]

Comment: Why can't you "solve this problem by editing capabilities" ? - that is exactly what they are designed for...

Comment: If I remove the capability `edit_essays` then the user role is unable to view this table to be able to grade/approve the essay. The ability to "grade/approve" the essay and view the essay table are both linked to the capability `edit_essays`

Comment: This sounds like a design problem, not ( yet ) a technical one, perhaps look to see if you can filter the caps available to make them different, if that is the cause of the problem - that would allow you to attribute caps for each step.